# Postgresql. Выбор строк из таблицы #1, id которых отсутствуют в таблице #2 с условием

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Здравствуйте! Есть 2 таблицы, примерный вид:

Таблица 1: "notification":

```
userId | type
-------------
1      | 1
2      | 2
3      | 991
4      | 991
```

Таблица 2 "user":

```
vkId   | something
-------------
1      | 1111
2      | 2222
3      | 3333
4      | 4444
```

Как выбрать пользователей из 2ой таблицы, но только тех, которых нет в таблице №1 с type = 991?

Вроде что-то такое должно сработать, но нет, всё равно выдаёт пользователей из таблицы 1 у которых type = 991.

```
SELECT "user"."vkId"
FROM "user" as "user"
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT "notification"."userId"
  FROM "notification" AS "notification"
  WHERE "notification"."type" = 991
    GROUP BY "notification"."userId"
    LIMIT 100
) AS "notification" ON "notification"."userId" = "user"."vkId"
WHERE "notification"."userId" IS NULL
GROUP BY "user"."vkId"
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT "user"."vkId"
  FROM "user" as "user"
  LEFT JOIN "notification"
    ON "notification"."userId"="user"."vkId"
   AND "notification"."type" = 991
 WHERE "notification"."userId" IS NULL
 GROUP BY "user"."vkId"
 LIMIT 100
```

Так же можно использовать NOT EXISTS (в некоторых случаях он может быть быстрее, хотя в других - медленнее чем LEFT JOIN):

```
SELECT "user"."vkId"
  FROM "user" as "user"
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM "notification"
         WHERE "notification"."userId"="user"."vkId"
           AND "notification"."type" = 991
       )
 GROUP BY "user"."vkId"
 LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT "user"."vkId"
FROM "user" as "user"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "notification" as "notification" ON "notification"."userId" = "user"."vkId"
WHERE "user"."vkId" NOT IN (
   SELECT "not"."userId"
   FROM "notification" AS "not"
   WHERE "not"."type" = 991
GROUP BY "user"."vkId"
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, в PostgreSQL должно работать:

```
select vkId from "user"
except
select userId from "notification" where "type" = 991
```