# Выборка из MySQL записей без ссылающихся

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы, одна содержит общие данные по пользователям, вторая более конкретные:

**Таблица 1 (трафики)**:

`ID, трафик, периодичность, активный`

**Таблица 2 (подключены)**:

`ID юзера, ID трафика, израсходовано, подключено`

Нужно как-то найти трафик по периодичности, активному, но чтобы у пользователя (в таб. 2) не было ссылки на этот ID трафика. Т.е. у пользователя может быть подключен только 1 тип трафика.

Пробовал через

```
WHERE traffic.ID = user.trafficID AND user.id != [ID юзера], 
AND traffic.active = [true] AND traffic.periodic = [6] limit 1;
```

В квадратных скобках то, что php подставляет в условие.

И если результат == 0 строк, то пользователя подключают.

Но, если у трафика есть ещё какой другой "подцепленый" юзер, то выдаёт эту самую запись и выходит уже не 0 строк, -> юзер получает возможность дважды приписать себе такой трафик.

Поиск по ID трафика невозможен, только по параметрам периодичности, активности и периоду обновления.

Как можно задать запрос, чтобы по параметрам, если запись с `user.trafficID` уже есть возвращает 0 строк?

Comment: посмотрите, думаю эти способы должны помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566842/194569

Comment: @Mike, опять выручаешь :) Спасибо, завтра попробую вечером, выглядит обещающе :)

Comment: Может и я тупой последние 2 дня... Но не могу разобраться даже с подсказкой @Mike...  В общем, надо выбрать из таблицы по параметрам, но вывести только в том случае, если параметры совпадают и НЕ существует записей с таким user.id вовсе... Счас выводит трафик, на котором другой юзер + тот самый юзер, т.к. id юзера на данной конкретной записи другой, хотя по id трафика есть запись с этим id юзера :( Мож непонятно изъяснился, пишите - попробую лаконично описать.

Comment: `select * from Таблица1 A where условия AND not exists(select 1 from Таблица2 Б where Б.ID-трафика=А.ID)` видимо как то так. либо описывайте задачу более полно, потому что не до конца ясно что требуется

Comment: Извиняюсь, ибо сам по-ходу не до конца понимаю задачу... В общем, во второй таблице может быть несколько "ссылок" на id в первой. Можно как-то проверять так, чтобы выбрать все записи из второй таблицы, имеющие общий id из первой и подходящие по остальным параметрам далее отсеивались, если есть id клиента и оставались только записи, где их нет? Прости, @Mike, добрый человек :) Сам запутался и тебя запутал :)

Comment: Тут получается что-то вроде двухуровневой проверки, насколько я понимаю, т.е. сперва выборка по основным параметрам - результат таблица всех трафиков, подходящих под поиск. Потом поиск по второй таблице с подстановкой id трайиков и вывод только тех, где id юзера не встречается...

Comment: Метод, приведённый в комметарии "select * from Таблица1 A where условия AND not exists(select 1 from Таблица2 Б where Б.ID-трафика=А.ID)" выдаёт запись с другим id юзера трафика, на котором уже висит юзер искомый...

Comment: Извиняюсь, @Mike за неудобства :) Однако это Я тупой и лыжи потому не едут XD Не подставлял A и В после имени таблиц и ссылки в условиях писал с именем таблиц. При использовании А и В всё получилось :) Может ответом свой комментарий с примером запроса выведешь, хоть в карму плюсиком капну :) Заслужил :)