# Связать две таблицы join'ом при связи 1:М

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Есть две таблицы Детали и Тестирование.
Нужно вывести все детали, не проходящие тестирование в определённом году. Есть 2 особенности:

1. Есть детали которые вообще не проходят тестирование, их надо выводить тоже;
2. Есть детали которые проходят тестирование по много раз, и таких много. Связь 1 : М.
   Написал вот такой запрос:

   select distinct name

   from Detales dt

   left join Testing ts on ts.ID_Detail = dt.ID

   where ts.DateBegin not like '%2015%'

Но из-за второй особенности выборка получается неверная, выводятся детали которые были протестированы. Переписал вот так :

```
select name
from Detales dt
where dt.ID <> (select distinct ID_Detale
                from Testing ts
                where ts.DateBegin like '%2015%')
```

Работает, но такой запрос слишком громоздкий. Как можно написать его используя один селект?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566836/postgresql-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-1-id-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-2-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb/566842#566842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM Detales dt
LEFT JOIN Testing ts ON ts.ID_Detail = dt.ID AND EXTRACT(YEAR, ts.DateBegin) = 2015
WHERE ts.ID_Detail IS NULL
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.